# Rails: Indicating that a model has an observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observer-pattern

A model I've implemented needs to escape/format one of the fields into an html-friendly version of the entered text (for the sake of argument, lets say it's a blue/redcloth stlye thing).

I implemented this in an observer with the before_save callback, all working, no complaints. I am learning rails as I code and it struck me that from just looking at the model there is no indication that it has an observer.

Is there a neat way of indicating (for other programmers who may view/edit my code) that a model has an observer or should I just do this in a comment (or not at all).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you do not need to specify on the target class/model that it has an observer all you need to do is make sure that the observer lists which models it is observing.

```
class ContentObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :answer, :audio_clip, :document
  #This right here ^

  def after_update(record)
    record.recent_activity.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was more the other way round though. I gather that using your code here you can have a single observer fire its callbacks on several models / non inferrable models. It was from the model's perspective I was thinking, there's no way (from your example) of realizing that the answer model would fire this callback purely from looking at the answer model code, I was wondering if there was a way. Think I'm just going to stick a comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a spec/test file for the observer.  If, in the future, someone changes the model in a way that upsets the observer then the spec/test will fail which will alert them.